# Problem using any type of queries on MongoDB Compass

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I just started using MongoDB and everything that goes with it.
Whenever I enter a query in Mongosh, I either get no output or this error :

"Error: clone(t={}){const r=t.loc||{};return e({loc:new Position("line"in r?r.line:this.loc.line,"column"in r?r.column:......)} could not be cloned."
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CuEj.png)

For example here is the query : "db.restaurants.find(
{ $or : [ { " cuisine ": " Italian " }, { " address . zipcode ":"10075" } ] }
)

Several other find methods didn't work and I couldn't use "mongoimport −−db sid −−collection restaurants −−drop −−file data.json" to import my json file, I had to manually import it into Compass (I had the exact same error).

Am I missing something here?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You get this unhelpful error if the query is not closed or is malformed, e.g. the following query works:

- db.restaurants.find( { "borough": "Manhattan" } )

but leave out the last bracket:

- db.restaurants.find( { "borough": "Manhattan" }

and you get that error. In your example the problem is the initial ", the following works fine:

- db.restaurants.find( { $or : [ { "cuisine": "Italian" }, { "address.zipcode":"10075" } ] } )